# What does *(void **) mean in c?

Tags: c

It is my understanding that `void **`, is a `void` pointer *to* a pointer. So then what does the third dereference operator do? We are Dr referencing the pointer that we are pointing to?

Comment: Where have you seen a `void**`?

Comment: There's only one dereference operator there. The stars after `void` are prt of a type name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `void**` is a pointer to a `void*`. `void**` is *not special in any way* - it's just a pointer to something, where that something happens to be a `void*`.

`(void**)something` casts `something` to a `void**`.
`*something` dereferences `something`.
Therefore, `*(void**)something` casts `something` to a `void**`, and then dereferences it (yielding a `void*`).

Answer (score 2):

No, you are dereferencing a pointer-to-a-pointer, thus obtaining a pointer to a piece of memory with no specified type.

Dereferencing a `void**` type (which in this case is obtained via a cast), will go to the memory location specified by that value and read enough bytes to obtain another pointer (which is of type `void*`).

Comment: Note: this causes undefined behaviour if the memory location was not a variable of type `void *`  (or a malloc'd space that had had a `void *` value written into it) . Nevertheless it is a somewhat common technique

Answer (score 0):

`void **` is a `void pointer` which is pointing to a `pointer` pointing to some other `variable` (let the variable be 'x').
So `*(void **)` gives you access to the content of 'x'.

Comment: This is what I thought, but I think paddys answer below is correct over yours